# Why won't my post request work in my Express app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, knex.js

I am developing a personal project and I can't figure out why my post request for saving user data doesn't work. Mainly I'm a frontend dev but recently I wanted to learn backend so this is all very new to me. For this project I am trying to use a modern tech-stack (even though it is not cloud based) and I have everything divided into modules. I know some things in the code are unorthodox, but I just want it to work for now (please don't judge too much). The tech is Express and some of the libraries used are routing-controllers, class-validator, Knex.

This is the error I get when I try to hit this endpoint:

```
Error<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at new HttpError (E:\moji radovi\Projekat Zlatna Lopta (Bojan)\Back\node_modules\src\http-error\HttpError.ts:16:18)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at new BadRequestError (E:\moji radovi\Projekat Zlatna Lopta (Bojan)\Back\node_modules\src\http-error\BadRequestError.ts:10:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at E:\moji radovi\Projekat Zlatna Lopta (Bojan)\Back\node_modules\src\ActionParameterHandler.ts:249:30<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at async ActionParameterHandler.normalizeParamValue (E:\moji radovi\Projekat Zlatna Lopta (Bojan)\Back\node_modules\src\ActionParameterHandler.ts:149:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

This is my controller:

```
@HttpCode(201)
    @Post('/save-user')
    async saveUser(@Body({ validate: {groups: ['registerUser']}}) user: UserBody): Promise<UserDTO> {
      const isDeleted = 0
      const userRole = 'user'
      const password = await this.crypter.encryptPassword(user.password);
      const existingUser = await this.userRepository.getUserByEmail(user.email);
  
    if (existingUser) {
      throw new CustomError(401, "User with this email already exists");
    }
      const userData = await this.userRepository.saveUser(
        user.username,
        password,
        user.email,
        userRole,
        isDeleted
        )
        return userData
    }

This is my repository method:async saveUser(
    username: string,
    password: string,
    email: string,
    role: string,
    id_deleted: number
    ): Promise<UserDTO> {
    const userRole = 'user';
  
    // Insert the user data into the database
    try {
      await this.database.instance('user').insert([{
        username : username,
        password: password,
        email : email,
        role: role,
        is_deleted: is_deleted
      }]);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new CustomError(500, 'Error saving user data to the database: ' + error);
    }
    return;
  }
```

I don't know If this has something to do with validation or what is the issue, but I'm stuck on this for about a week and it's starting to be painful.
If this is of some help here are my UserDTO and UserBody files:

```
export class UserBody {
    @IsString({ groups: [] })
    @IsOptional({ groups: ['registerUser'] })
    uuid: string
  
    @IsString({ groups: ['registerUser', 'saveUser'] })
    @IsNotEmpty({ groups: ['registerUser', 'saveUser'] })
    username: string
  
  
    @IsEmail({}, { groups: [ 'registerUser','login', 'findUser', 'saveUser'] })
    @IsNotEmpty({ groups: [ 'registerUser','login', 'findUser', 'saveUser'] })
    email: string
  
    @IsString({ groups: ['resetPassword', 'registerUser', 'login','saveUser'] })
    @IsNotEmpty({ groups: ['resetPassword', 'registerUser', 'login', 'saveUser'] })
    @MinLength(5, { groups: ['resetPassword', 'registerUser', 'login', 'saveUser'] })
    @IsDefined({ groups: ['resetPassword'] })
    password: string
  
    @IsString({groups: ['saveUser'] })
    @IsNotEmpty({ groups: ['saveUser'] })
    role: string
    
    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional({groups: ['saveUser'] })
    id_deleted: number
  

    }export class UserDTO {
      @IsNotEmpty()
      @IsNumber()
      @IsOptional()
      user_id: string
    
      @IsString()
      @IsNotEmpty()
      @MinLength(3)
      username: string
    
      @IsString()
      @IsNotEmpty()
      password: string
    
      @IsEmail()
      @IsNotEmpty()
      email: string
    
      @IsNumber()
      role: string
    
      @IsNumber()
      @IsOptional()
      is_deleted: number
    
    }
```